# I am learning bootstrap 3 and I am not getting where to place jquery codes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to put it in script and without script tag.Suppose we have to run following code.What should we do?I have included proper bootstrap css and js files.

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the script is running before DOM ready? Try

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle') 
});
```

Other than that, either jQuery or bootstrap js file might not be included properly.